# Calling function in template repeat

Tags: binding, dart, polymer

Need update a table that looks like that:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{mainList}}" index-as='mainListIndex'>
 <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{mainList}}" index-as='secondListIndex'>
  {{getValueFromListOfLists(mainListIndex, secondListIndex)}}
 </template>
</template>
```

When mainList a changed, function getValueFromListOfLists not call again.

```
@PolymerRegister('matrix-component')
class MatrixComponent extends PolymerElement {

  @Property(reflectToAttribute: true)
  List<List<Map>>  matrix;

  @Property(reflectToAttribute: true)
  List mainList;

  MatrixComponent.created() : super.created();

  @reflctable
  getValueFromListOfLists(firstIndex, secondIndex){
    return matrix[statusFromIndex][statusToIndex]['info'];
  }
}
```

How i can update that?

Comment: I guess it's only called if one of `mainListIndex` or `secondListIndex` is changed for that item.

Comment: But if it not changed? And List matrix changed and I need to show all the new values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the function gets called when `mainList` updates, you have to pass that as an argument to the function ([docs on dependent properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#dependent-properties)).

```
{{getValueFromListOfLists(mainListIndex, secondListIndex, mainList.*)}}
```